# JXDatePicker and selectAll()

Tags: java, swingx

I want a listener that autoselects the entry on the JXDatePickers editor cell when same gains focus.

```
DatePicker.getEditor().selectAll();
```

doesn´t work. So i tried this :

```
DatePicker.getEditor().addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    DatePicker. getEditor().selectAll();
                }
             });
        }

public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
}
});
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

just realized that you probably have stand-alone datepicker, and run your snippet: worksforme. So we'll need to dig for differences - what's your swingx/jdk version and OS?

**Original**

typically, the JFormattedTextField is tricky to convince being selected ;-) See

[Combining JXTable with RXTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365397/combining-jxtable-with-rxtable)

and adapt the solution to handle JXDatePicker as well - by adding

```
    if (editor instanceof JXDatePicker) {
        LOG.info("got picker: " + editor);
        invokeSelectAll(((JXDatePicker) editor).getEditor());
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Didn´t realize i had an answer, sorry.
Swingx 1.6.2, JDK6u14, win7-64.